# How to replace content with additional key and value in Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, replace

```
StreamWriter myfile = new StreamWriter(@"d:/into.txt");

string MyStringFile = @"
  | Domain: domainName12
  | UserName: paswordchange
  | PassWord: abc12";

Dictionary<string, string> myv = new Dictionary<string, string>();

myv.Add("abc12", "thi user");
myv.Add("paswordchange", "wer2345");
myv.Add("domainName12", "www.abc.com");

string MyStringFileNew = "";

foreach ( KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in myv)
{
    MyStringFileNew = MyStringFile.Replace(pair.Key.ToString(), pair.Value.ToString()).ToString();
}
```

I am trying to replace some content with my above sting using a `Dictionary` but the only last one key `www.abc.com` has been successfully replaced.

I am using C#

Comment: Strings are immutable. You're not modifying MyStringFile, just assigning the modified value to MyStringFileNew. Try MyStringFile = MyStringFile.Replace(..., ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using unchanged string to replacing your values.

Change your code to :

```
foreach ( KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in myv)
{
    MyStringFile = MyStringFile.Replace(pair.Key.ToString(), pair.Value.ToString()).ToString();
}

MyStringFileNew = MyStringFile;
```

Or do this to prevent changing original string:

```
MyStringFileNew = MyStringFile;

foreach ( KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in myv)
{
    MyStringFileNew = MyStringFileNew.Replace(pair.Key.ToString(), pair.Value.ToString()).ToString();
}
```